# : could not connect to redis Instance at XX.XXX.XX.XXX:6379

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, servicestack

Hi I am trying to connect to a redis server listening on port 6379 on AWS EC2 linux server.

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager(new[] {"XX.XXX.XX.XXX:6379"}));
```

I performed following steps , created a inbound rule as Custom TCP allowing 6379 port ,and changing redis.conf bind to XX.XXX.XX.XXX:6379 or 0.0.0.0 but still unable to connect to server , can anyone help.

Here is my inbound rule on AWS

```
Custom TCP Rule TCP 6379 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: You are trying to connect to the Redis from EC2 Instance or from your local machine?

Comment: Can you make sure it's an external IP and not an internal IP? Try using the public DNS entry for the instance listed in the details on the EC2 AWS console. Could you also paste your exact `/etc/redis/redis.conf` with `bind 0.0.0.0` entry just to make sure?

Comment: What @Layoric said, or just use AWS ElastiCache - it's super simple to set up, link to existing EC2 architecture and maintain(Amazon does it for you for the most part) plus it gives you the choice between Redis and MemCached!

Comment: @error2007s Yes am trying to connect to Redis onEC2 instance from my local machine.

Comment: @Layoric sorry i didnt get your point on "make sure its an external IP and not internal IP".? is it a check done on AWS side..?

Comment: Check the port config for the port 6379 on your local machine. Is that port open.

Comment: @error2007s yes the firewall configured to open port 6379 , and am unable to connect to public DNS through mobile also, the site cant be reached message apears, is somethng wrng with aws.?

Comment: Make sure your http port 80 is open to world for the EC2 instance. Custom TCP Rule TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: @error2007s the port 80 is also open to world. i have used just the publicIp:6379 in my program to connect to aws , do i need any additional things to be done locally ..? Because, configurations are seems to be good on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

Enable telnet on your local machine. Run:
telnet XX.XXX.XX.XXX 6379

ensure that the IP you are trying to connect to is accessible from your machine.

ensure that redis is configured properly to connect on the public IP